# Plotting a heatmap with interpolation in Python using excel file

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, heatmap, colormap

I need to plot a HEATMAP in python using `x, y, z` data from the excel file.
All the values of `z` are `1` except at `(x=5,y=5)`. The plot should be red at point `(5,5)` and blue elsewhere. But I am getting false alarms which need to be removed. The COLORMAP I have used is 'jet'

```
X=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
Y=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Z=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Code I have used is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import ravel
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
X= excel_data_df['x'].tolist()
Y= excel_data_df['y'].tolist()
Z= excel_data_df['z'].tolist()
  
x_list = np.array(X)
y_list = np.array(Y)
z_list = np.array(Z)

#   f will be a function with two arguments (x and y coordinates),
# but those can be array_like structures too, in which case the
# result will be a matrix representing the values in the grid
# specified by those arguments
f = interp2d(x_list,y_list,z_list,kind="linear")
x_coords = np.arange(min(x_list),max(x_list))
y_coords = np.arange(min(y_list),max(y_list))
z= f(x_coords,y_coords)

fig = plt.imshow(z,
           extent=[min(x_list),max(x_list),min(y_list),max(y_list)],
           origin="lower", interpolation='bicubic', cmap= 'jet', aspect='auto')

# Show the positions of the sample points, just to have some reference
fig.axes.set_autoscale_on(False)
#plt.scatter(x_list,y_list,400, facecolors='none')
plt.xlabel('X Values', fontsize = 15, va="center")
plt.ylabel('Y Values', fontsize = 15,va="center")
plt.title('Heatmap', fontsize = 20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

For your ease you can also use the X, Y, Z arrays instead of reading excel file.

The result that I am getting is:

[image]

Here you can see dark blue regions at `(5,0)` and `(0,5)`. These are the FALSE ALARMS I am getting and I need to REMOVE these.
I am probably doing some beginner's mistake. Grateful to anyone who points it out. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three problems in your example:

- `x_coords` and `y_coords` are not properly resampled;
- the interpolation `z` does to fill in the whole grid leading to incorrect output;
- the output is then forced to be plotted on the original grid (`extent`) that add to the confusion.

Leading to the following interpolated results:

[image]

On what you have applied an extra smoothing with `imshow`.

Let's create your artificial input:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 11)
y = np.arange(0, 11)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.ones(X.shape)
Z[5,5] = 9
```

[image]

Depending on how you want to proceed, you can simply let `imshow` smooth your signal by interpolation:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.imshow(Z, origin="lower", cmap="jet", interpolation='bicubic')
```

[image]

And you are done, simple and efficient!

If you aim to do it by yourself, then choose the interpolant that suits you best and resample on a grid with a higher resolution:

```
interpolant = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, Z.ravel(), kind="linear")

xlin = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
ylin = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
zhat = interpolant(xlin, ylin)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.imshow(zhat, origin="lower", cmap="jet")
```

[image]

Have a deeper look on [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) module to pick up the best interpolant regarding your needs. Notice that all methods does not expose the same interface for imputing parameters. You may need to reshape your data to use another objects.

#### MCVE

Here is a complete example using the trial data generated above. Just bind it to your excel columns:

```
# Flatten trial data to meet your requirement:
x = X.ravel()
y = Y.ravel()
z = Z.ravel()

# Resampling on as square grid with given resolution:
resolution = 11
xlin = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), resolution)
ylin = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), resolution)
Xlin, Ylin = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

# Linear multi-dimensional interpolation:
interpolant = interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator([r for r in zip(x, y)], z)
Zhat = interpolant(Xlin.ravel(), Ylin.ravel()).reshape(Xlin.shape)

# Render and interpolate again if necessary:
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.imshow(Zhat, origin="lower", cmap="jet", interpolation='bicubic')
```

Which renders as expected:

[image]

Comment: Its not working in my code. Can you implement these snippets in my code but I have to take input from excel file only.